# PowerShell function parameters

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

Why does the first call to square work, but the second does not:

```
function add ($arg1, $arg2){
    return $arg1 + $arg2
}

function square ($arg1){
    $arg1 * $arg1
}

Write-Host (square (add 1 2 ))

Write-Host (square (add (1, 2)))
```

Comment: I just saw that commas aren't used to pass in arguments in powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you see the problem, but I will post a fuller description for the good of all.

In your first line, your inner call to `add` is passing two parameters (integers).  The function returns an `int` and the `square` function squares it.

In the second line, you are passing one array containing two integers.  This results in the `add` function adding one array to nothing and returning an array.  Then the `square` function tries to take that array and multiply it by itself.

You should get an error that looks like this:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
At line:1 char:8
+ (1,2) * <<<<  (1,2)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
```